# Prove that $m^*(aE)=|a|m^*(E)$

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

For $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, we consider the function $f(x)=ax+b, x\in \mathbb{R}$. Show that:
$\forall E\subseteq\mathbb{R} $ measurable, $m*(f(E))=|a|m^*(E)$

---

$f(E)=aE+b$, it's known that $m^*(E+x)=m^*(E)$, so it's enough to show that $m^*(aE)=|a|m^*(E)$

I don't know why it doesn't say $a$ should be $\geq 0$ since if $E=(c,d)$, where $d>c>0$ and $a<0$ it doesn't exist the interval $aE$.

Anyway, I am assuming $aE=|a|x$, $\forall x\in E$.
In order to prove this, I need to show that if $I$ is an open interval then $l(aI)=|a|l(I)$, indeed let $I=(x,y)$ then $aI=(|a|x,|a|y)$ then $l(aI)=|a|y-|a|x=|a|(y-x)=|a|l(I)$

If $I_n$ is an open cover of $E$ then $aI_n$ is an open cover of $aE$ $\Rightarrow$ $m^*(aE)=inf\{\sum_n l(aI_n)\}=inf\{\sum_n |a|l(I_n)\}=inf\{|a|\sum_n l(I_n)\}=|a|m^*(E)$

Comment: $aE$ is defined as the set $\{ae, e \in E\}$ so for example $-2[0 , 1] = [-2 , 0 ]$.

Comment: It doesn't say that $a \geq 0$ because that is not necessary:  hence the $|a|$ in the punchline.

Comment: What definition do you have of Lebesgue mesure ?

Comment: @InfiniteLooper $m^*(E)=inf\{\sum_n l(I_n), \text{where} (I_n) \text{is an open cover of} E\text{ by intervals}\}$

Comment: What is your question then ?

Comment: @InfiniteLooper it's in tag solution-verivication, I don't have a question, i just want to make sure its correct

Comment: If you don't have any question, i don't have any answer :p

Comment: @InfiniteLooper you didn't say my proof was correct, I am assuming it is since you didn't comment on that. Then we are good

Comment: Note that  your definition of the measure is not Lebesgue one.